# How do I fix the line breaks in my solution after changing the git config file

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I've cloned a GIT repository and gone to run the unit tests, however they are failing because a text file that is parsed has `\n` line breaks, but because this is a Windows machine, it is expecting line breaks to be in the form of `\r\n`.

From what I've read, adding `autocrlf = true` to the config file should make it normalise the line breaks when checking in/checking out. Is this true?

My problem now is that the files that have already been downloaded from source control have the `\n` line breaks, and not the `\r\n` breaks. How do I force my solution to download just those files with the correct breaks? I have some uncommitted changes that I'm not quite ready to push.

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

- stash your changes
- create the '.gitattributes' (instead of relying on the 'autocrlf' setting that's the old way to do...)
- commit it
- (here your tests should pass)
- unstash your changes